# Java Game: How to store a name entered in textfield and display in a label upon button press

Tags: java, textfield

I'm trying to display a name in a textlabel after it is entered in a textfield and pressed a 'Play' button.

The text field and button

```
private JTextField nameEnter = new JTextField("Enter name here");
private JButton saveName = new JButton("Play");
private JLabel namelabel = new JLabel("Player 1");
```

To add to board and position

```
getContentPane().add(nameEnter);
getContentPane().add(saveName);
getContentPane().add(namelabel);
nameEnter.setBounds(80,80+gize*bsize,200,50);
saveName.setBounds(100,100+gsize*bsize,200,50);
namelabel.setBounds(40,40+gsize*bsize,200,50);
```

This displays fine.

```
  public void UpdateName() {
          JButton saveName = new JButton("Play");
                   saveName.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                   {
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
                        {
                        final String pName = nameEnter.getText();
                             namelabel.setText(pName);
                        }
                    });


  }
```

I tried to create the above method to store it but this doesn't seem to do anything at all.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: when do you call `UpdateName()`? i think if you remove the line `JButton saveName...` from `UpdateName()`and add a call to `UpdateName()` at the end of display init code, it will work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `UpdateName()` method is creating its own local `JButton saveName` button and adding `ActionListener` to it. Problem is that this button is not the same as button you added to your content pane.

I am not sure why you even need this method. Simplest solution would be placing code responsible for adding this listener

```
saveName.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
          namelabel.setText(nameEnter.getText());
     }
});
```

in initializing method (somewhere after `getContentPane().add(saveName);`)

Answer (score 1):

The method does:

- Create a new button
- Attach a listener

  - On action (click), update the name

To reuse the existing `saveName` button you already added to your layout,
drop the line that creates a new button, that is:

```
  public void UpdateName() {
       saveName.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                 final String pName = nameEnter.getText();
                 namelabel.setText(pName);
            }
        });
  }
```

Comment: Ok thanks, i'll rename the method. As for getContentPane().add(saveName); I have added the line already with the other objects I positioned.